# Render PartialView using ajax after select item from dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have the following ViewModel

```
public class ReservationDetails
    {
        public ReservationDetails()
        {

        }
        public Reservation Reservation { get; set; }

        public List<ReservationHouseDetails> ReservationHouseDetails { get; set; }

        public Dictionary<string,ReservationHouseDetails> MyProperty { get; set; }

        public List<ReservationAttractionDetails> ReservationAttractionDetails { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Houses { get; set; }

        public int SelectedHouseDetailsId { get; set; }

        public string SelectedHouseDetailsText { get; set; }
    }
```

When I open view Details.cshtml it displays me DropdownList with the name of houses. I would like to select one of them and after click button display in partial view content in some div of selected House.
How should I correct the follwing script to render partial view using ajax

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.SelectHouse').click(function() {
  $('.divForSelectHouse').Load('@Html.Partial("~/Views/ClientReservations/ReservationHouseDetails.cshtml",Model.MyProperty[Model.SelectedHouseDetailsText])')
});
    </script>
```

I think it should be the additional method in controller, resposible for displaying partial view like this

```
public PartialViewResult DetailsHouse(ReservationHouseDetails houseDetails)
        {
            return PartialView("ReservationHouseDetails", houseDetails);
        }
```

In this case how can I pass object as parameter to this method, if it must be serialized, how it should look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Html.Partial()` is server side method, it will be called before rendering HTML. In your case you need to bind some some partial view based on selection of drop down. So what you need to do is, you need to call the partial view's controller method by ajax.

```
$('.SelectHouse').click(function() {

 $.ajax({  url: @Uri.Action("ActionName","ControllerNmae"),
           type: "post",
           dataType:"html",
           data: "<your data as serialized json>",
           success: function(result) {
              $('.divForSelectHouse').html(result);
            }
         });
});
```